# Defining constants using existence proofs in Coq

Tags: coq

After proving an existence statement, it is often notationally convenient to introduce a constant symbol for some witness of this theorem.

As a simple example, it is much more simple to write (in typical mathematical notation)

```
∀x. ∅ ⊆ x.
```

than it is to write

```
∀x. ∃y. empty(y) and y ⊆ x.
```

I am looking to replicate this effect in Coq.  Here is the basic scenario I am encountering and my attempt which leads to an error (now in real Coq code):

```
Variable A:Type.
Hypothesis inhabited: exists x:A, x=x.

Definition inhabitant:A.
  destruct inhabited.  
  (*Error: Case analysis on sort Type is not allowed for inductive definition ex.*)
```

I am wondering what this error message even means and if there is any way to get around this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is related to the usual `Prop vs Type` distinction. The existence of your witness lies in `Prop` (see definition of type `ex`), so you can't inspect it to build a concrete term, you need to have this fact proved in `Type`.

You are looking for the `sig` (or a variation like `sigS` or `sigT`) type whose notation is :

```
Hypothesis inhabited : {x : A | x = x }.
```