# Defining function in Coq

Tags: function, coq

Let assume that:

```
Axiom inverse1: forall a:G, exists b:G, P a b.
Axiom only_one: forall a b1 b2:G, P a b1 /\ P a b2 -> b1 = b2.
```

These two axioms define a map G -> G. I want to define this mapping as a Coq function.

Comment: Your problem is the same as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28765188/defining-constants-using-existence-proofs-in-coq

Answer (score 2):

You can't define this function in Coq without relying on extra information or axioms. The problem is that the `exists` quantifier lives in sort `Prop` (i.e., it is a proposition), and Coq's logic prevents one from using the proof of a proposition or an axiom to build terms of computational nature in most cases (i.e. things whose type lives in `Type` or `Set`, as `G` in your example probably is). Check the [reference manual](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual006.html#sec186) (section 4.5.4) for more information. Instead of assuming axioms like the ones you gave, theories in Coq would tend to assume just the existence of a function:

```
Axiom f : G -> G.
Axiom f_in_P : forall x : G, P x (f x).
```

Comment: "Coq's logic prevents one from using the proof of a proposition or an axiom to build terms of computational nature" do you can give me a link?